# How to display a modal dialog on click of an option in context menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, modal-dialog, contextmenu

I need a modal dialog to pop up when I select an option ("configure" option in my case) from a context menu(which originates from inside a jsplumb flowchart component). I have "userlogged.jsp" which is where the flowchart components appear. "demo.js" is where the context menu function resides. "index.jsp" has just the modal that I need to be displayed on top of the contents of userLogged.jsp.

This is part of demo.js

```
   $(function() {
     $.contextMenu({
          selector : '.context-menu-one',
           callback : function(key, options) {
              $(document)
        .ready(
                function() {
                    fromMenu();

                });
              if (key == "configure") {

                  fromMenu();
              }
       },
       items : {
              "configure" : {
                     name : "configure",
                     icon : "edit"
              },
              "delete" : {
                     name : "Delete",
                     icon : "delete"
              }
          }
       });
    });
```

This is index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

       <!doctype html>
        <!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
       <html class="no-js" lang="en"
data-useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

          <meta name="description"
content="Documentation and reference library for ZURB Foundation. JavaScript, CSS, components, grid and more." />
           <meta name="author"
content="ZURB, inc. ZURB network also includes zurb.com" />
           <meta name="copyright" content="ZURB, inc. Copyright (c) 2015" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/foundation.css" />
           <script src="src/js/modernizr.js"></script>
           <script src="src/js/jquery.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document)
        .ready(
                function() {

                    $('#firstModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');

                    //checks for the button click event
                    $("#sec")
                            .click(
                                    function(e) {
                                        var username = $("input#username")
                                                .val();
                                        var root = $("input#root").val();
                                        var password = $("input#password")
                                                .val();
                                        var db = $("input#db").val();
                                        var port = $("input#port").val();
                                        dataString = "username=" + username
                                                + "&root=" + root
                                                + "&password=" + password
                                                + "&db=" + db + "&port="
                                                + port;
                                        $.ajax({
                                                    type : "GET",
                                                    url : "DbInformation",
                                                    data : dataString,
                                                    success : function(data) {
                                                        var data = JSON.parse(data);
                                                        alert(data);
                                                        console.log(data.length);
                                                        $("#countrytable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                                                        var table1 = $("#countrytable");
                                                        for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                                            var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td></tr>");
                                                            rowNew.children().eq(0).html(("<select id='tabl'  name=mytextarea size=3 height = '20px' ><option name=one value="+data[i]+">"+ data[i] + "</option></select>"));
                                                            rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    });
                    $("#third").click(
                            function(e) {
                                var tabl = $("#tabl").val();
                                var username = $("input#username").val();
                                var root = $("input#root").val();
                                var password = $("input#password").val();
                                var db = $("input#db").val();
                                var port = $("input#port").val();
                                dataString = "username=" + username
                                        + "&root=" + root + "&password="
                                        + password + "&db=" + db + "&port="
                                        + port + "&tabl=" + tabl;
                                $.ajax({
                                    type : "GET",
                                    url : "DbInformation",
                                    data : dataString,
                                    success : function(data) {
                                        var data = JSON.parse(data);
                                        alert(data);
                                        var dd = "";
                                        console.log(data.length);
                                        $("#columns").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                                        var table1 = $("#columns");
                                        for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                            var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td></tr>");
                                            rowNew.children().eq(0).html(("<select id='tabl'  name=mytextarea size=3 height = '20px' ><option name=one value="+data[i]+">"+ data[i] + "</option></select>"));
                                            rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                });
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>



        <div id="firstModal" class="reveal-modal tiny" data-reveal>
            <h2>Properties.</h2>
            <p>
                Username : <input type="text" id="username" name="username"
                    value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                root : <input type="text" id="root" name="root" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                password : <input type="text" id="password" name="password"
                    value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                db : <input type="text" id="db" name="db" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                port : <input type="text" id="port" name="port" value="3306">
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" id="sec" data-reveal-id="secondModal"
                    class="secondary button">Next</a>
            </p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>

        <div id="secondModal" class="reveal-modal tiny" data-reveal>
            <h2>This is a second modal.</h2>
            <table id="countrytable">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Table name</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p>
                <a href="#" id="third" data-reveal-id="thirdModal"
                    class="third button">Next</a>
            </p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>

        <div id="thirdModal" class="reveal-modal tiny" data-reveal>
            <h2>This is a second modal.</h2>
            <table id="columns">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Column name</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p>
                <a href="#" id="fourth" data-reveal-id="thirdModal"
                    class="fourth button">Finish</a>
            </p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>




<script src="src/js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/foundation.tab.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
    var doc = document.documentElement;
    doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
</script>
    </body>
     </html>
```

How do I get this modal that is generated in index.jsp to appear on top of userlogged.jsp on click of the configure option in the context menu defined in demo.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want the modal dialog over the contents of "userlogged.jsp", then I think you should put the code (for the modal dialog) in that page itself, because if it navigates to a separate page (like index.jsp) then it won't be much of a modal dialog (because it has *already* navigated to the other page).

one way of doing this having the modal dialogs HTML code in the parent page itself (which is "userlogged.jsp" in your case if I am not wrong), setting its visibility to hidden (so that it doesnt show by default) and on triggering of a perticular event (like clicking on a perticular context menu), setting the visibility as normal (so that it comes up as a modal dialog over the existing page).
Also make sure you take care of removing that modal as well (by setting the visibility to hidden) on a certain event (like clicking an "OK" button on the modal dialog).

Hope it helps!